Main character had a Mickey Mouse wristwatch
Saw a watch face on my colleague smartwatch had a Mickey Mouse theme. I remembered there was some film where the main character (I think) had an old Mickey Mouse watch from his childhood and was still using it and reluctant to give it up, which film was that from?
It was a big Hollywood title and possibly a comedy, perhaps from 90s

You'll need to give a bit more detail than that.  There are a lot of films with Mickey Mouse watches in them.

It's an identify this movie question, if I had more to go on I'd have found it myself or remembered.

I wonder why someone downvoted this question... Looks fairly legitimate to me!

-1 already? Christ, what's wrong with that question (except that it was an unfortunate duplicate)?

@Nobilis How is it a duplicate?

@NapoleonWilson There's already an answer that discusses the movie where this item features, perhaps the suggestion system didn't identify it. If it had, possibly OP would have been happy with the answer. I can't otherwise explain the downvote.

The suggestion system does show the other question....

@Nobilis But that's not technically a duplicate in any way. The asker doesn't know that it's about this movie and he's asking a completely different and genuine question. The downvote might simply be due to being a short identification question quite lacking in detail.

@NapoleonWilson I understand, I don't think it's still fair. Especially for somebody asking a question for the first time and not been given a chance to edit it.

Although this one isn't exactly from the 90s, Pretty sure this is from The Da Vinci Code (2006 film).
The main character, Robert Langdon wears a Mickey Mouse wrist watch.

More information about the watch.

Hah yes! I edited with "possibly" a comedy which was apparently how I associated with this film in particular

@Recc - not exactly a comedy :P

@Stark07 Hanks was once considered a comedy actor (his oeuvre is much broader now), so understandable.

Yeah fair enough
